# angularJS: loop inside an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to display data from a certain part of a string of JSON data.

Below is the part i want to display.

{
          "-rank": "3",
          "-teamId": "t3",
          "-name": "Arsenal",
          "-played": "31",
          "-won": "17",
          "-drawn": "7",
          "-lost": "7",
          "-for": "52",
          "-against": "30",
          "-points": "58",
          "-goalDifference": "22"

Below is the JS.

```
 $scope.leagueTable = $scope.myData.LeagueTable.Table.TeamPosition;
                                //League Table
            for( var i = 0; i < $scope.leagueTable.length; i++) {
                if($scope.leagueTable[i]['-teamId'] == "t3") {
                    $scope.arsenalStats = $scope.leagueTable[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
            console.log($scope.arsenalStats);
```

And below is the HTML I am using. I just get blank results. no errors.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="val in leagueTable| limitTo:-1">
  <div class="col">{{arsenalStats[$index]['-played']}}</div>
  <div class="col">{{arsenalStats[$index]['-won']}}</div>
  <div class="col">{{arsenalStats[$index]['-drawn']}}</div>
  <div class="col">{{arsenalStats[$index]['-lost']}}</div>
  <div class="col">{{arsenalStats[$index]['-points']}}</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It is not displaying the data from just that particular team.

Comment: arsenalStats is not array. So you can't use arsenalStats[$index]. If you want to display only arsenalStats, you don't need ng-repeat. {{arsenalStats['-played']}} enough.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks! if you want to make it an answer I can vote it up.

Answer (score 0):

using `leagueTable` object, you should be using `val`.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="val in leagueTable| limitTo:-1">
  <div class="col">{{val[$index]['-played']}}</div>
  <div class="col">{{val[$index]['-won']}}</div>
  <div class="col">{{val[$index]['-drawn']}}</div>
  <div class="col">{{val[$index]['-lost']}}</div>
  <div class="col">{{val[$index]['-points']}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using this still displayed nothing for me.